# Eclipse J2ME -a error has occurred during deploying application

Tags: java, eclipse, java-me

Hi i am new to J2ME programming i created a new basic J2ME project in eclipse

New->Project->J2ME->J2ME Midlet Suite named HelloWorld

then

New->other->J2ME->J2ME Midlet named HelloWorld

when i run the project it shows

A problem occured during deploying application from localhost:53803/ota/HelloWorld/HelloWorld.jad
Reason:
JAD not found

the emulator starts but it shows 2 option install application and manage certificate authorities

Please anyone help me

Comment: You are using NetBeans, right?

Comment: I am having the same problem. Using NetBeans 2.7.1